# react native: what is the way to narrow column?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-native-table-component

My example has a table of 2 columns with equal size `Containers_Count` and `Containers_Description`, I want to narrow the column of `Containers_Count` only.
What is the way to do this?
I would be happy for some help with this.

```
import { Table, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';

const SikumHamechalim = () => {
  const [sikumVisible, setSikumVisible] = useState([]);
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([]);

  const arrangeData = () => {
    let rows = [];
    sikumVisible.forEach(e => {
      let row = [e.Containers_Description, e.Containers_Count];
      rows.push(row);
    });
    setTableData(rows);
  }
  useEffect(() => { arrangeData(); }, [sikumVisible]);

  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.Secondary_title}>
        <Text style={styles.secondaryTitleText}>
          Choose
    </Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.DividerLine}></View>
      <ScrollView style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{ borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff' }}>
          <Row data={tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text} />
          <Rows data={tableData} textStyle={styles.dataText} />
        </Table>
      </ScrollView>
    </>
  )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { backgroundColor: '#fff' },
  head: { height: 40, backgroundColor: '#f1f8ff' },
  text: { margin: 6, fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 16, alignSelf: 'center' },
  dataText: { margin: 10, fontSize: 16, textAlign: 'center' },
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can narrow the column by with `flexArr` prop (See [`Properties`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-table-component#properties) section).

The value of `flexArr` depends on the ratio you want between the first and the second column. (In the example below the ratio is 1:3)

```js
<Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 1}}>
  <Rows data={tableData} flexArr={[1, 3]} />
</Table>
```

https://snack.expo.io/@moshfeu/narrow-column